# C'est quand même le choix le meilleur et le plus résistant pour votre moteur

Tags: expressions

> Pourquoi choisir une huile moteur entièrement synthétique ? Même si
> votre garantie n'exige pas l'utilisation d'une huile moteur
> synthétique, c'est quand même **le choix le meilleur** et le plus résistant
> pour votre moteur. ([source](https://www.castrol.com/fr_ca/canada/home/motor-oil-and-fluids/motor-maintenance/how-to-check-your-engine-oil.html))

Je ne trouve pas beaucoup d'exemples contenant *le choix le meilleur* sur Internet. Est-ce que ce tour est correct ?

Comment: Il y a deux adjectifs. **Peut-être** pour cette raison. Sinon, le meileur choix, et le plus résistant,

Comment: @Lambie Please do not answer in comments. That's not how StackExchange works. *Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.*

Comment: I was not sure at all. Therefore, I used a comment.

Comment: @jlliagre Tell this person, too: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50010/email-ending-equivalent-to-cheers

Comment: Je suis absolument d'accord avec @jlliagre. Il aurait été préférable d'écrire une réponse et non un commentaire. Par contre, rédiger rarement un commentaire dans le but d'**aider** la personne qui a posé une question est une chose, c'en est une autre de critiquer sans cesse les autres et de publier des commentaires qui ne répondent pas à la question.

Answer (score 2):

Bien que beaucoup plus rare que ***le meilleur choix***, le tour ***le choix le meilleur*** est tout à fait correct et idiomatique.

Je n'en dirais pas autant de la suite de la phrase. ***Le choix le plus résistant*** ?? Ce n'est pas le choix qui résiste, c'est l'huile !

L'original anglais dit ***the strongest and best choice** for every engine* qu'on aurait mieux traduit par **le choix le plus sûr, le meilleur** pour votre moteur [...]

D'autres formes peu ou pas idiomatiques, calques de l'anglais, parsèment les pages de ce site. Par exemple :

1. Il est donc une bonne pratique de...
2. Rouler avec un bas niveau d'huile est incroyablement dommageable...
3. Il est d'une importance vitale que l'huile moteur usée [...] se rende à un centre de recyclage...  (*makes it to a recycling center*).

Comment: The strongest and best choice [of oil, implied] for every engine: le choix de l'huile le meilleur et le plus résistant pour tout moteur

Comment: Merci beaucoup. :) // Serait-il possible d'écrire _**Il est d**'une bonne pratique_ ? // Je n'ai pas trouvé la 2ème phrase sur cette page. Par contre, il y a _Car ajouter trop d’huile moteur est aussi **dommageable** pour votre moteur que de ne pas en avoir assez, et peut causer des dommages graves, particulièrement aux véhicules dotés de convertisseurs catalytiques._ Elle est correcte, à mon avis. // Comment ajoutes-tu des bonshommes et d'autres images à tes réponses ?

Comment: @Oreste ***C'est une** bonne pratique de* ou mieux, **il est recommandé de**, l'expression *bonne pratique* étant relativement récente et d'abord cantonnée à certains jargons. **Rouler avec un niveau d'huile trop bas est extrêmement dommageable** (ou **préjudiciable**). La phrase que tu as reprise est correcte, encore qu'une relecture aurait sûrement remplacé soit *dommageable*, soit *dommages*, le français ayant horreur des répétitions.

Comment: @Lambie *le choix de l'huile le meilleur et le plus résistant pour tout moteur* est une bien piètre traduction. On s'offusque ailleurs de l'accord du participe passé, mais ici, on n'hésite pas à transgresser le genre oléagineux...

Comment: You said that: "Le choix le plus résistant ?? Ce n'est pas le choix qui résiste, *c'est l'huile*" ! " And you said: le choix le meilleur. So, **le choix de l'huile le meilleur et le plus résistant**. is the **logical result of your comments**.

Comment: Pour l'[anglais](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60764635#60764635). Peut-être une idée de question...

Comment: @Lambie Je me répète, mais un choix ne peut pas être résistant. Ta proposition n'est donc pas le résultat logique de mes commentaires puisqu'elle est en contradiction avec au moins l'un d'entre eux.

Comment: **Je ms suis de trompée de genre**:  "le choix ||d'huile la meilleure et la plus résistante. Il suffit de mettre **huile et le féminin**.

Comment: @Lambie Je te l'avais pourtant écrit noir sur blanc mais comme tu l'a déjà mentionné ailleurs, tu ne connais pas tous les usages du pronom *on*.  Pour ce qui est de ta nouvelle proposition, c'est mieux, mais ce n'est toujours pas très idiomatique.

Comment: The on pronoun question is not this question. I have **never ever seen anything like that with on**. Ask it as a question and see what response you get. It never agrees in number like that as you claim: On était allé**s**. Please, don't insult me.

Comment: Never agrees in number, why wouldn't it? *De jeune fille en jeune fille, on était allés jusqu'à Chicago.* Yvan Audouard, *Liqueurs fortes*, 1971, and hundreds of other examples in printed books.

Comment: Only when the actual other terms are there: In the question he gave us, there wasn't. You assumed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135148/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).