# Email ending: equivalent to 'cheers'

Tags: traduction, anglais, correspondance, email

According to many sources such as [https://www.24seventalent.com/blog/2016/04/cheers-sincerely-best-how-to-sign-off-on-a-professional-email#:~:text=In%20particular%2C%20we%20recommend%20cheers,you%20stand%20out%20just%20enough](https://www.24seventalent.com/blog/2016/04/cheers-sincerely-best-how-to-sign-off-on-a-professional-email#:%7E:text=In%20particular%2C%20we%20recommend%20cheers,you%20stand%20out%20just%20enough).

> Unless your email is going to a particularly formal or traditional business professional, "fondly" and "yours truly" both fall into the same category as "sincerely": they work, but they're formal and monotonous.
> As a global staffing agency, we always recommend showing your
> personality – within reason – when it's appropriate. To that end,
> cheers, best, and take care have all become front-runners in the
> modern age of email professionalism. In particular, we recommend
> cheers. What was once a quaint British phrase for saying goodbye has
> become a mainstay in American professional email culture, offering an
> upbeat, simple, and perfectly professional option for ending your
> emails. It’s pleasant, unique, and will make you stand out just
> enough. So far I’ve only encountered one company that uses cheers to
> end its emails and my experience has always been… cheery.

What are some words or expressions that could convey 'cheers' in the end of a professional (but not formal) email?

Comment: Can you show us your research about the French here?

Comment: Je dirais _Bien cordialement_ ou _Bien à vous_ pour la France ; _Merci et bonne journée_ est plus courant au Québec. Après, il y a _Bonne journée_, _En vous souhaitant une bonne journée_. J'ai certainement oublié qq expressions. _Au plaisir_ aussi.

Comment: Could you please expand a little on why _cheers_ is upbeat and pleasant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les formules de politesse dans le cadre professionnel proposées par [Quelles formules de politesse utiliser dans vos mails professionnels ?](https://www.netoffensive.blog/content-marketing/lead-nurturing/formules-de-politesse-mail/) sont parmi celles pas trop formelles  proposées au début de leur liste ; elles sont recopiées ci-dessous.

- Cordialement,
- Salutations distinguées,
- Sincères salutations,
- **Cordiales salutations**,
- Sincèrement,
- Bien sincèrement,
- Bien cordialement,
- **Meilleures salutations**,
- Au plaisir de vous revoir, Au plaisir de vous voir ([BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4946)),
- Au plaisir de collaborer,
- Bonne matinée,
- Belle journée,
- Excellente fin de semaine,

On peut ajouter celle-ci trouvées au site [cadremploi](https://www.cadremploi.fr/editorial/conseils/conseils-carriere/detail/article/quelle-formule-de-politesse-utiliser-dans-un-mail-professionnel.html).

- Bien à vous

Sur [indeed](https://fr.indeed.com/conseils-carrieres/cv-lettres-motivation/formule-de-politesse-mail) on découvre l'option supplémentaire suivante.

- Amitiés,

Le site [internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/actualite/guide-vie-quotidienne/1413282-formule-de-politesse-exemples-et-bons-usages/) s'arrête sur une variante de la possibilité précédente.

- Amicalement,

Voici quelques idées en plus qui viennent du [site du gouvernement du Canada](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_f&page=9sItSGqits4A.html).

- **Avec mes cordiales salutations**,
- Bien cordialement,
- Toutes mes amitiés,
- Meilleurs souvenirs,
- Affectueux souvenirs,
- Mon bon souvenir,
- **À bientôt**,
- **Au revoir**,

Additions de [dynamique-mag](https://www.dynamique-mag.com/article/formules-politesse-utiliser-e-mail-e-lettres.11302)

- Bon week-end,
- Bonne lecture,

Précisions de [droit-finance](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/faq/3043-formule-de-politesse-exemples-et-conseils-pour-vos-lettres-et-mails)

- bonne soirée,

« En pratique, l'expression la plus utilisée à la fin des courriels est "Cordialement", notamment en cas d'envoi de mails groupés. Les souhaits comme "Bonne journée" ou "Bonne soirée" sont également très courants, à condition naturellement des les utiliser au bon moment de la journée... »

[ouest-france](https://ideetexte.ouest-france.fr/formules-politesse.html#formules-politesse-emails)

- Cordialement vôtre,

[DICOCITATIONS](https://www.dicocitations.com/formule-politesse.php) préconise la composition.

- Vous pouvez aussi composer :...cordialement vôtre, ...mon amical souvenir, ...toute notre amitié, ... mes sentiments amicaux, ...mes sincères salutations, ... mes meilleurs sentiments,

[BDL](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4946)

- Sincèrement vôtre,

Toutes ces possibilités conviennent, mais si l'on veut rester factuel on devrait utiliser les expressions en caractères gras. Il existe une possibilité pour laquelle je n'ai pas de référence mais que j'ai trouvée dans une lettre qui m'était adressée ; c'est la formule toute simple « *salutations* ».

Comment: Je n'ai jamais vu _au revoir_ dans un mail ; pourtant il devrait être acceptable, d'autant que _à tantôt_ et _à bientôt_ sont employés. _Affectueux souvenirs_ et _Mon bon souvenir_, je ne les ai pas vus non plus. Vous, est-ce que vous êtes tombé sur ces tours ? _Meilleurs souvenirs_ non plus. // _si l'on veut rester factuel on devrait utiliser les expressions en caractères gras_ Oui ?... Y compris votre _au revoir_ ?

Comment: @Oreste 1/  Je n'ai jamais vu « Au revoir » en fin de lettre non plus, pas plus que  « Affectueux souvenirs », « Mon bon souvenir », et « Meilleurs souvenirs » ; en ce qui concerne les courriels, je ne sais pas car il est très rare que j'en écrive ou que j'en reçoive. 2/ Il me semble que ce devrait être une des expressions mise en évidence puisque le sens de « Cheers » en anglais est « goodbye » et que l'on traduit généralement ce dernier terme en français par « au revoir ».

Comment: _Il me semble que ce devrait être..._ Probablement. // En ce qui me concerne, je n'écris jamais de lettres, et je reçois pas mal de mails. D'habitude, on écrit _(Bien) cordialement_ ou _(Merci et) bonne journée_ à la fin.

Comment: Bonne recherche !

Answer (score 1):

*[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/cheers/569664) bilingue en ligne* suggère comme traduction *salut* et *tchao* (l'orthographe réformée de *ciao*) pour le sens de *goodbye*. Dans certains cas ça pourrait être « merci et salut ! ».

Comment: Je dois dire je vois beaucoup _Cordialement_ dans le courriel. Beaucoup.

Comment: Même au Québec ? Ici, je vois plutôt _Bonne journée_.

Comment: @Oreste J'avais pas allumé que tu parlais de _cordialement_, je pensais que tu parlais du contenu de la réponse. Pour cordialement, oui, au Québec, je vois ça beaucoup dans les courriels que je reçois.

Comment: Oui, je parlais de ton premier commentaire, de _cordialement_ dans les courriels au Québec. C'est vrai, j'aurais dû écrire de façon plus claire.