# Comment traduire ou transposer « the strongest and best [quelque chose] » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs, formulation-idiomatique, superlatifs

> We have the **[strong](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/strong/615506)est and best** system of higher education in the
> world. So many major changes and scientific advancements over the last
> few decades have come out of a research university, not a corporation.
> From a research university. People all over the world want to come
> here for that.
>
> [ alors ancien Vice-President Joe Biden, [UB 2018-2019](https://www.buffalo.edu/ubnow/stories/2018/10/biden-dss.html), je souligne ]

Je viens de remarquer que cette cooccurrence des adjectifs *[strong](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/strongest)est* et [*best*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/best) coordonnés est plutôt fréquente, que ce soit en politique, en [mécanique](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/50007) ou autrement. Des [locuteurs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60764635#60764635) anglophones l'ont *perçue* comme une forme d'intensification (*emphasis*) ou d'exagération plutôt verbeuse, une fioriture, un lieu commun un peu creux ou pas particulièrement significatif (je paraphrase).

---

- Comment va-t-on traduire ou transposer cette cooccurrence ici ;
  va-t-on aussi employer deux adjectifs superlatifs coordonnés, une
  locution ou autrement, ou omettre un adjectif et simplifier ?

  - Pourquoi pense-t-on traduire ou non de la même manière qu'il s'agisse
    de qualifier l'*enseignement supérieur* ou l'*huile à moteur* ?

    - Quelle serait une méthode stylistique typique pour ajouter du
      poids à son propos en étirant la sauce et qui permettrait peut-être
      d'obtenir un effet similaire (voire une réaction similaire des
      locuteurs) ?

Comment: Je n'ai pas voulu éditer avant de vérifier. Il me paraît que tu maîtrises mieux que moi la langue française:-)! 'Des locuteurs anglophones l'ont perçu"**E**', n'est-ce pas ? (cette cooccurrence des adjectifs perçue)

Comment: @Dimitris J'avais volontairement choisi de faire l'accord avec « adjectifs s & b coordonnés »... haha je blague. Tu peux mettre un _e_. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

"Nec plus ultra" me semble une traduction correcte. "Fin du fin", "l'alpha et l'oméga en matière de", sont des candidats qui restituent également à mon sens la *tonalité* que peut avoir "strongest and best" en anglais : un truc un peu verbeux, un peu daté, qui fleure bon l'enthousiasme abstrait qui présidait à "l'esprit de système" de la fin du XIXème.

Le fin du fin est peut-être le meilleur de ceux-ci. Nec plus ultra a une connotation technique qui est singulièrement absente de "strongest and best", éloge plus littéraire que scientifique. Et "alpha et oméga" instille en creux une idée d'exhaustivité, de somme, qui se heurte à l'approche relative du "strongest and best". Voilà qui me ferait préférer le fin du fin, comme traduction de strongest and best.

Alternativement, un mot un peu désuet comme "pyramidion" pourrait faire le taf.

Comment: DeepL « Nous avons le système d'enseignement supérieur ***le plus solide*** et le meilleur au monde. » garde cette tonalité médiocre [https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9diocre A1] par cette nuance de *force* remplacée par *solide* (notion statique), *puissance* (notion dynamique). Selon le contexte ou l'intention *efficace, capable, compétente*. — « Pyramidion » désuet et oublié dans cette acception par plus de 99,7 % de francophone (il en reste sûrement à la Sorbonne avec quelques philologues adorateurs de ces sommités :-) .